# Where are the apple-app-site-association files cached/stored on iOS when Universal Links are used?

Tags: ios

The official documentations states that when users install your app, iOS checks a file that you’ve uploaded to your web server to make sure that your website allows your app to open URLs on its behalf. Only you can create and upload this file, so the association of your website with your app is secure.

So I am wondering where does iOS keep the fetched **apple-app-site-association** file cached/stored? Keychain? Local storage?

Answer (score 1):

It's stored in keychain. You check it on device, after wiping out keychain you lose universal links.